# Floating/fixed div in footer

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have a wordpress site and I would like to display 1 Google Adsense banner ad (320px x 50px) at the very bottom of the page only to mobile users. When I say at the bottom of the page I should really say the bottom of viewable screen so no matter where on the page the user is it's always visible.

I have worked out that I need to use media queries and I have found out the size of the main mobile devices that use the site which are either 320px or 360px wide.

The css I wrote for this and placed in the standard style.css file is;

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 360px) {
.mobileadunit {
  width:320px;
  height:50px;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0px;
  }

}
```

I then placed the div in the footer.php file on wordpress just before the  tag

```
<div class="mobileadunit">
ADSENSE CODE
</div>
```

but despite my best efforts I can't get this to show up. Am I doing something wrong that's glaringly obvious?

Comment: "so no matter where on the page the user is it's always visible" Watch out: It is "unacceptable to place Google ads in a "floating box" in which ads scroll, hover, or expand over the webpage" [found here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense/lisYPOjLbxE). Sticky ads are prohibited currently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that css "@media queries" alone probably would not deliver the result nor the best user experience for what you want.

First of all, I'm not a specialist but more of a learner too. Anyway, as for now it seems Google's AdSense ads are a fixed size, and don’t adapt to different screen widths when viewed on different devices. On smaller devices, when browsing responsive websites, AdSense ads would expand outside of their container, and oftentimes off of the screen – breaking the layout, degrading the user’s experience, and even keeping mobile visitors from clicking on your ads.

#### SO, ARE THERE ANY WORKAROUNDS?

Yes, if you search the web you'll find a few solutions for it, including Google's official recommendations on alteration to AdSense code. I've already came through this issue once, and after a really quick research I got to know 2 really nice plugins to display AdSense ads on responsive WordPress websites. See [Google AdSense for Responsive Design Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-adsense-for-responsive-design-gard/) (Free option) and the [Easy Responsive AdSense Plugin](http://codecanyon.net/item/easy-responsive-adsense/4489695) (Paid option) as well.

As mentioned before, [Google Adsense program's policies](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1354736?hl=en&topic=1271508) covers their own methods and directives for alteration to Adsense code, and although their accepted modification guidelines are pretty straightforward and highly recommended, as long as one doesn't modify the Adsense code in a way it is harmful for the program, then Google does accept minor modification to Adsense code without applying any penalties to the user's account.

Either by using a plugin or not, javascript + css media queries would be the best approach to achieve a better experience for the expected result based on your question. If you do not want to rely on a plugin, you can follow the steps below to make it work with a few pieces of css and js.

## THE SOLUTION:

So, based on the aforementioned plugins' solutions, I've built a quick [demonstration](http://goo.gl/sZ5P4E) (live test website) so you can access/test it on your mobile phone. The demo website displays the AdSense mobile banner (320x50px) only on mobile phones, as also other ad units with different size formats only on common mobile devices by detecting their screen sizes with the help of media query, and then with a very simple javascript we instruct/tell Google to choose the best ad size to be displayed when the page is loaded.

Keep in mind that this code is responsive when the page first loads, but won’t be responsive for any subsequent changes to window size or device orientation. When browsing the demo website, please consider refreshing the page every time the window size is changed.

Additionally, you can play with it on [CODEPEN](http://cdpn.io/gwExA) as well, but remember that in order to make it work, you should replace AdSense client number and ad slots numbers with your own. [Here's a few screenshots](http://cl.ly/1p2i441J0I2J) of it working on iOS 7 mobile safari iPhone 5.

So let's break it into pieces:

### First, let's set the HTML markup:

The AdSense mobile banner and the other ad units with different sizes will be rendered based on the current width of the **`<div>`** with **`id="responsive-adsense`"** right within the **`<div>`** with **`id="adcontainer"`**, which is in turn, is the one we'll use to position the banner always fixed in the bottom.

```
<div class="adcontainer">

<div id="responsive-adsense">
<!-- AdSense javascript goes here -->
</div>

</div>
```

### Then embed AdSense javascript right away:

Here, I've commented out the good hints.

```
<div class="adcontainer">
<div id="responsive-adsense">

 <script type="text/javascript">
  // Replace google_ad_client number with ith your AdSense Publisher ID
  google_ad_client = "ca-pub-928637890363315";
  // Detect and calculate the width of the "<div>" where AdSense ads will be rendered
  var containerWidth = document.getElementById( "responsive-adsense" ).offsetWidth;
  // If ad container is 728px...
   if ( containerWidth >= 728 ) {
  //...Then, display Adsense ad of size 728x90px
  // Remember to replace the AdSense Ad Slot ID as well for all the different size ad units
  google_ad_slot = "2385224440";
  google_ad_width = 728;
  google_ad_height = 90;
    }
  // If ad container is 468px, then display Adsense ad of size 468x60px
   else if ( containerWidth >= 468 ) {
  google_ad_slot = "1350406442";
  google_ad_width = 468;
  google_ad_height = 60;
   }
  // If ad container is 320px, then display Adsense ad of size 320x50px
   else if ( containerWidth >= 320 ) {
  // It is even possible to set a different google_ad_client ID only for your mobile traffic
  google_ad_client = "ca-pub-928637849363315";
  google_ad_slot = "1350806442";
  google_ad_width = 320;
  google_ad_height = 50;
   }
  // If ad container is 234px, then display Adsense ad of size 234x60px
   else if ( containerWidth >= 234 ) {
  google_ad_slot = "2825039647";
  google_ad_width = 234;
  google_ad_height = 60;
   }
</script>

<script src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</div>
</div>
```

The javascript code above covers 4 specific ad units. Google recommends not modifying AdSense code in order to display more than 3 ad units on the same page, so it is advisable to set only 3 ad units within a unique page. As long as we'll be displaying only 1 ad within a unique page according to a device's screen size we're good to go. Be sure to take sometime and read Google's AdSense policies [here](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/48182).

We're covering 4 ad units with different sizes with the javascript code above, as follows:

- 234 x 60 - Half Banner
- 320 x 50 - Mobile Banner
- 468 x 60 - Banner
- 728 x 90 - Leaderboard

### Now with the help of css for media query we'll target the most common small screen sizes

We'll be covering an extend approach to display the AdSense ads across a variety of screen sizes with the help of css media queries below, which in turn, would target most mobile devices such a smartphones and tablets. We're not being strictly oriented to any specific mobile device here, thus, you can always build your own targeting scheme or simply stick with the Adsense Mobile banner (320x50) portion of code only, as it is showed on this approach...

According to your question, you do not want to display this on desktop browser, so we'd start by setting `display: none;` for everything when browsing the website on desktop.

```
/* Default Stylesheet */

#responsive-adsense {
  display: none; 
}

#responsive-adsense{
  display: none;
} 


/*
GENERAL MEDIA QUERY FOR SMALL SCREEN SIZES - COVERS COMMON MOBILE DEVICES, PHONES/TABLETS...
*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px) {

.adcontainer {
  display: none; 
}

#responsive-adsense{
  display: none;
} 

}


@media only screen and (max-width: 899px) {

.adcontainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  display: block;
  background: #e74c3c;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
 }

#responsive-adsense {
  width: 728px !important;
  display: block !important;
}

}


@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {

.adcontainer {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0px;
 display: block;
 background: #e74c3c;
 color: #fff;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 5px;
}

#responsive-adsense {
 width: 728px !important;
 display: block !important; 
}

}


@media only screen and (max-width: 599px) {

.adcontainer {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0px;
 display: block;
 background: #e74c3c;
 color: #fff;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 5px;
}

#responsive-adsense {
 width: 468px !important;
 display: block !important; 
}

}


@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {

.adcontainer {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0px;
 display: block;
 background: #e74c3c;
 color: #fff;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 5px;
}

#responsive-adsense {
 width: 320px !important;
 display: block !important;
} 

}

/* Here's the css for mobile devices */  
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {

.adcontainer {
 width: auto !important; 
 padding: 0px !important;
 height: 50px !important; 
}

#responsive-adsense {
 width: 320px !important;
 display: block !important; 
}

}
```

Last but not less important, you can always follow Google's responsive approach for setting up Adsense ads on your website and make your own changes as long as you do not infringe any of the prohibited terms of their policies. https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1354736?hl=en&topic=1271508

This may be not the best solution for you, but even Google points out their attempt is not yet perfect and accepts your own modifications when and where you consider it a necessity, again, any modifications to AdSense code should always be in accordance with the good practices of Google Adsense's policies.

### Additional references:

The following articles point two different methods in order to display AdSense ads on responsive websites the right way. Most of what was answered here derives from these sources as also Google's official recommendations.

Check it out, it might be really helpful for your needs:

http://www.labnol.org/internet/google-adsense-responsive-design/25252/

http://www.akshitsethi.me/google-adsense-responsive-ads-explained/

I hope this helps you and a few other fellows in the community. Any improvements are welcome.

Comment: This solution achieves what I need but with so much more! Thank you for such a comprehensive explanation, I'm implemented your suggestion and it works perfectly. The only thing I did was delete the background colour of the container so if the ad is smaller or no ad is served, the page behind it is visible.

Comment: Hey @JonathanRosenfeld - That's good to hear that it worked for you! Yeah, I set a background color just to highlight the ad container in the demo page. Anyway, it was indeed an extended answer and it seems it has some inconsistencies, but after a few corrections it's possible to make it even more clear to the other members as well. Please, remember to vote the answer up if it was really helpful for you. I wish you good luck on your projects. See you then!

Answer (score 2):

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
  .mobileadunit {
      width:320px;
      height:50px;
      position:fixed;
      bottom:0px;
      display:block;
  }
}
```

So I've switched the media queries so that it uses min/max-width instead of min/max-device-width, so that it'll work on a computer screen, but here's a jsfiddle of it working:

http://jsfiddle.net/hm3Cj/

This is a great article for the difference between just a min/max-width and min/max-device-width: http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries2.shtml (in case you're interested.) Also it has all of the common device/screen sizes. The current one that you're using is a rather small amount of space to display in. 320 x 480 might be a more useful ratio for a mobile phone.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**: This is working fine for me, Fixed Google AdSense in Bottom for mobile.

**HTML**

```
<div class="main_ad">
<div class="mobileadunit">
    <!-- Put Code Given By Google Adsense -->
    <script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXX"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
         style="display:inline-block;width:320px;height:50px"
         data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXX"
         data-ad-slot="XXXXXXXXXXX"></ins>
    <script>
        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main_ad{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 101;
  display: block;
}

.mobileadunit {
  display: none;
  margin:0px auto;
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 480px) {
  .mobileadunit {
    width:320px;
    height:50px!important;
    bottom:0;
    display:block!important;
    z-index: 1;
  }
}
```

**In Sort**

```
<div class="main_ad">
   <div class="mobileadunit">
    ADSENSE CODE
   </div>
</div>
```